# Locally reject pushed tags that don't exist on server

Tags: git, tags

We're using sourcetree, which pushes tags by default (if you have the checkbox selected) and someone keeps pushing old tags and temporary tags, mucking up our remote's tags.  We'd like to just disable the ability to push tags using a pre-push hook.

It seems like a simple task, but I cannot find anyone who has done this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in a file called `update` in the `hooks/` directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ $1 == refs/tags/* ]]
then
   echo "No tags allowed!"
   exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

**Edit**: if you *really* want a client side hook, put the following in a file called `pre-push` in each developer's `.git/hooks` directory (though according to [this page](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/215927/use-git-hooks-with-stash) it looks like normal scripts are supported in Stash):

```
#!/bin/sh

while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
    if [[ $local_ref == refs/tags/* ]]
    then
       echo "No tags allowed!"
       exit 1
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Comment: Is this a remote script?  I'm looking for a local script.

Comment: @JeffLamb, when you say "local script," do you mean a hook every developer has to install in their local git repo? This is indeed a script that is meant to be put on the remote, so that all users have to abide by the no tags policy.

Comment: Ah, that's what I thought you were going to say.  Yes, server-side is better.  However, we're using Stash as a remote, which requires you to write java plugins for stash.  That's annoying.  We've already devised a way to version control local hooks by copying to .git/hooks as a step in our build.  I know this is super hacky and has security implications, but this is a closed-source dev environment with <10 people.  Way easier to commit a change to a hook than it is to recompile and reinstall a java plugin.

Comment: OK @JeffLamb, your wish is my command; I have added a client hook to the answer. Though as I mention in the answer, it does look like Stash supports "normal" hooks as well.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Genie - and thanks for the link on supporting normal hooks on the remote.  Now I get to remove this hack - whew.  I found the repo storage on the server, but was greeted with a directory of a ton of numbered directories, which I thought was some compressed version of the repos.  Sure enough, they're the normal repos stored there.